# OAuth 2 Close Tabs after Success Login

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

I'm facing problem when using OAuth 2 in my application, after a succefull login and redirection to my App ( browsable app ) i want to force closing tabs that i used in for login ( i'm using browser not webview ).

Any solution that i can do to force closing this tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a mobile app to invoke the external system browser, but not to close it afterwards. There is a preferred solution that usually meets the same goals though.

Use the AppAuth pattern, which works like this:

- The user signs in via an integrated form of the system browser called a Chrome Custom Tab
- This feels natural from a UX viewpoint, and the app can close this window when login completes
- It is also good from a security viewpoint since the app itself never sees the user's password

See [this Curity code example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/kotlin-android-appauth/) for a visual walkthrough.